# How to check if KVM nested virtualization is supported on ARM64 processor?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, rhel8, arm

I have a virtual machine running RHEL 8.5 on an ARM64 (`aarch64`) processor - Arm Neoverse N1.

Every tutorial I've found states looking at either `/sys/module/kvm_amd` or the `/sys/module/kvm_intel` folder to figure out whether nested virtualization is enabled, but my VM does not have any of those. There is however a `/sys/module/kvm` folder which I figured is the right folder.

But the file which is used to determine whether nested virtualization is on (`/sys/module/kvm/parameters/nested`) is absent. It's not possible to create the file either because it's a read only folder. Trying to run Kata Containers (which uses QEMU) fails with:

```
Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
qemu-system-aarch64: failed to initialize kvm: No such file or directory
```

How is it possible to check whether nested VT is enabled, or how to enable nested VT?

Comment: What did the kernel say? (try `dmesg | grep -i kvm`)

Comment: @anx Here is the output:
`[    0.161629] DMI: QEMU KVM Virtual Machine, BIOS 1.5.1 06/16/2021
[    0.998613] kvm [1]: HYP mode not available
[    1.190231] systemd[1]: Detected virtualization kvm.
[    1.199640] systemd[1]: Initializing machine ID from KVM UUID.
[   14.789151] systemd[1]: Detected virtualization kvm.
[13368.413034] systemd[1]: Detected virtualization kvm.
[2168829.663102] systemd[1]: Detected virtualization kvm.`

Comment: uodate your question not post this as comment. the vm is running as qemu cpu, it should be running as native to support this. It looks for me that it is emulate a arm processor